# tabula-py: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache

Tags: python, java, tabula, tabula-py

I'm unsuccessfully trying to read a PDF in Python using `tabula-py`. I installed Java (both `jre-1.8` and `jdk-20`), set up `JAVA_HOME` path (`C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8\bin` in my case; I also added it to `Path`) and still cannot run `read_pdf` method. Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

from tabula import read_pdf
from tabulate import tabulate

file_name: str = "to_tabulate.pdf"

df = read_pdf(file_name)

print(tabulate(df))
```

Output (shortened):

```py
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File org.jpype.JPypeContext.java:-1, in org.jpype.JPypeContext.callMethod()

Exception: Java Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException          Traceback (most recent call last)
```

...

```py
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

...

```py
ImportError: Failed to import 'org.apache'
```

I can't find any solution for this particular problem and have absolutely no guess what causes this issue (I don't have any experience in Java and still considering myself as beginner in Python). The only interesting (let's say) thing I noticed is that in the traceback there's no mention of `org.apache` subclass (like e.g. `commons`) but just `apache` in general.

Has anyone encountered such problem before? Are there any solutions? Any help would be highly appreciated.

I use Windows 11 Pro 22H2 22621.2134, Python 3.11.1 and `tabula-py` 2.8.1.